# How to use Array for validation in Firestore Rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

In Firestore I have a collection which stores multiple objects, which are shared by multiple users.
example:

```
{
  users: [uid1, uid2, uid3],
  content: 'sample'
}
```

All of these three users should be able to see the doc. For that, I created the following rule:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /sharedDocs/{doc} {
      allow read: if isMember(doc);
      allow update: if isMember(doc);
    }

    function isMember(doc) {
      return doc.indexOf(request.auth.uid) != -1;
    }
  }
}
```

I send the query by Angular (AngularFirestore Module):

```
return this.db.collection('sharedDocs,
  ref => ref.where('users', 'array-contains', uid)
).valueChanges();
```

Unfortunately, I get the following Error on this query:

> ERROR FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

Comment: Rules will only reject operations once you run code against them. Can you edit your question to include the minimal code you need to run to get that error message?

Comment: OK. I added the query.

Comment: Hmm... I don't know if this is possible in security rules. But I'm hoping @DougStevenson may show up and confirm.

Comment: Ok. I thought so. Do you have an idea for a different security strategy for the same use case?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen if it is not possible. Maybe I allow read, only from front end hostname. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a security rule where you can use an array for validation. You can use `in` condition to check if a particular value is present in the array.

Consider an example where you need to restrict the creation of a new document with an existing uniqueId, i.e if the user has already created the document with the same `uniqueId` and its uniqueId is existing in the array of `createdDocs` in his/her user document in the `Users` collection .

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /Docs/{uniqueId}{
      //Only restricting new docs 
      allow create: if  (! uniqueId in getUserData(request.resource.data.userId).createdDocs); 
    }       

    //Function to get the user information
    function getUserData(userId){
      return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Users/$(userId)).data;
    }             
  }
}
```

Try this, for your particular case:

```
match /sharedDocs/{doc} {
  allow read: if (request.auth.uid in resource.data.users);

}
```

**Note:** Please make sure that you check the same in your application as the firestore security rules simulator is known to have some issues.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is not working. It looks like that on read I'm not able to access the doc data. I tried also very simple with if content=='simple'

Comment: @NicoSchuck Are you getting error while reading the document?

Comment: I've added the modifications to your existing read rule so that read is allowed if the `uid` of the authenticated user is existing in the document's `users` array field which you are trying to access in the `sharedDocs` collection. Please check now.

Comment: I tried on the same way as you on reading. Unfortunately, I still get the same error.

Comment: @NicoSchuck, Did you try it on the simulator?